# f# and c# getting different answers for basic Math

Tags: c#, math, f#

I have the f# module

```
open System

module Scores =

    let DbToContinuous input = (((input / 1000) - 1) * 100) + (input % 1000)
```

That is the whole module (so far)

I have a C# function it was meant to replace (which looked very similar).

```
    private static int DbToRealScore(int dbScore)
    {
        return ((dbScore / 1000) - 1) * 100 + (dbScore % 1000);
    }
```

However, something is wrong. The two are not producing the same results.

Switching back to the C# version, I augmented it with the following:

```
private static int DbToRealScore(int dbScore)
    {

        var x = Scores.DbToContinuous(dbScore);
        var y = ((dbScore / 1000) - 1) * 100 + (dbScore % 1000);

        if (x != y)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Math error: [input: {dbScore}, x: {x}, y:{y}]");
        }

        return y;
    }
```

for an input of `4100`, I get the error message `Math error: [input: 4100, x: 500, y:400]`, demonstrating that the f# version is 100 too large. It has not subtracted the 1.

Even more strangely, the f# code works as expected when I use the f# interactive console...

```
> let y x = (((x / 1000) - 1) * 100) + (x % 1000);;
val y : x:int -> int

> y 4000;;
val it : int = 300

> y 4100;;
val it : int = 400
```

Any information on how I'm getting the two different answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Parenthesis are unnecessary and are for clarity only

Comment: * has a higher precedence than +

Comment: Also, the f# code is identical in both the interactive nad build versions (in terms of parenthesis), yet I get the two different answers between the two.

Comment: Are you sure all your dependencies are built and up to date? Try cleaning and rebuilding everything from scratch.

Comment: yeah tried that one. Didn't change anything. Even deleted the bin folder and rebuilt to no avail

Comment: Do you have a project reference (in the same solution) between the C# and the F# projects? The only explanation that I can see is that you're not actually running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the F# module and step through in the debugger. Does the F# code still look correct?

Comment: Project reference is right, otherwise it wouldn't build, much less run. Breakpoint not a bad idea, possibly will try messing with the function in other ways see if I can get it to do something deliberately wrong (e.g. add 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running clean on the f# project rather than the solution fixed it. I do not know why it doesn't get cleaned properly with the solution, but cleaning the project caused it to rebuild and get the correct result.